# web cam with gopro mount?

Tags: webcam

I have a bunch of GoPro (J-Hook Buckle) mounts and was wondering if there's a webcam that  could reuse these mounts.

A lot of webcams have fixtures that'll allow you to rest the webcam on your monitor. Some of small tripods but I like the versatility that GoPro's offer and would like a webcam with the same level of versatility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a GoPro as webcam! :)

Currently, GoPro Webcam mode is supported on:
•   HERO9 Black
•   HERO8 Black
•   HERO7 Black
•   HERO6 Black
•   HERO5 Black
•   HERO4 Black
Source: https://gopro.com/en/us/news/how-to-use-gopro-for-webcam

Or you could use a 3D printed structure to be able to use basically any webcam with the mounts.